# Визуализатор схем-выполненя запросов в Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Как я понимаю, Oracle не имеет многих вещей к которым я привык при работе с MS SQL Server и имеются "из коробки"...=(

Чем можно визуализировать планы выполнения запросов, что бы было так же удобно, как и в MS SQL Management Studio?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В приоритете бесплатные, а потом уже платные решения.

Comment: Вы лучше скажите как вы эти картинки понимали, там же что бы увидеть что то важное, надо мышь наводить на каждый значок, а потом помнить. И еще эта дурацкая картинка вечно на экран не влезает. приходится в бок двигать что бы хоть что то разглядеть. А в тексте у Oracle как раз все отлично, сразу все видно. Так что привыкайте :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

В дополнение к ответу от @MaxU.
Реальный план выполнения запроса может отличаться от того, который предоставляет `explain plan`.
Обычно, если я хочу посмотреть план выполняемого запроса, то сначала я получаю `sql id`(выглядит примерно так `ds9njzundv6k0`) нужного мне запроса.

```
select s.sql_id, s.* from v$session s
```

Дальше в зависимости от настроения есть несколько способов посмотреть план:

- 1 -В текстовом виде:

  ```
  SELECT * FROM TABLE (dbms_xplan.display_cursor('ds9njzundv6k0'));
  ```

  Результат будет представлен в текстовом виде:

  ```
  SQL_ID  9ya87b6a04kc3, child number 0
  -------------------------------------
  select s.sql_id, s.* from v$session s

  Plan hash value: 644658511

  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Id  | Operation                 | Name            | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)|
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT          |                 |       |       |     1 (100)|
  |   1 |  NESTED LOOPS             |                 |     1 |  1379 |     0   (0)|
  |   2 |   NESTED LOOPS            |                 |     1 |  1170 |     0   (0)|
  |*  3 |    FIXED TABLE FULL       | X$KSUSE         |     1 |  1009 |     0   (0)|
  |*  4 |    FIXED TABLE FIXED INDEX| X$KSLWT (ind:1) |     1 |   161 |     0   (0)|
  |*  5 |   FIXED TABLE FIXED INDEX | X$KSLED (ind:2) |     1 |   209 |     0   (0)|
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
  ---------------------------------------------------

      3 - filter(("S"."INST_ID"=USERENV('INSTANCE') AND 
                  BITAND("S"."KSSPAFLG",1)<>0 AND BITAND("S"."KSUSEFLG",1)<>0))
      4 - filter("S"."INDX"="W"."KSLWTSID")
  ```
- 2 - В виде HTML(вариант 1):

  ```
  select dbms_sqltune.report_sql_monitor( sql_id => '9ya87b6a04kc3',
                                          type => 'HTML',
                                          report_level => 'ALL + PLAN') as report
  from dual;
  ```

  В результате вернется `clob` поле содержащее HTML файл, который можно открыть в браузере
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- 3 - в виде HTML(вариант 2 с использованием Flash Player):

  ```
  select dbms_sqltune.report_sql_detail( sql_id => '9ya87b6a04kc3',
                                         type => 'ACTIVE',
                                         report_level => 'ALL+XPLAN'
                                       ) as report
  from dual;
  ```

  В результате вернется `clob` содержащее HTML страничку и использующее флеш плеер, что дает чуть более интерактивное отображение. В этом варианте на 1 из кнопочек можно увидеть графический план, на котором можно подергать мышкой.
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
  или в более традиционном для `Oracle` стиле
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**PS**

Способы 2 и 3 используются для построения интерфейса в Enterprise Manager, возможно там есть какие то тонкости с лицензированием. Поигравшись с параметром `report_level` можно получить различные результаты.

Comment: Провентилирую завтра на работе насчёт (PS) по поводу лицензии. В остaльном +1.

Comment: @0xdb краем уха слышал, что лицензия Оракла запрещает использовать то, за что не уплачено, даже если оно есть в стандартной поставке. И вот EM точно отдельная опция, а что на счет пакетов для генерации под него не понятно

Comment: Я так и понял, это и уточню. Сам пока не задумывался, т.к. юзил только пункт 1.

Comment: По-моему `dbms_sqltune` - интерфейс к `SQL Tuning Advisor` и чтобы чтобы им пользоваться надо обладать лицензией  [Oracle Tuning Pack](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBLIC/options.htm#DBLIC170)

Comment: Тут и начинаются вопросы, если дернуть его из пакета, это то же самое, что поставить галочку в ЕМе ?

Answer (score 7):

[`sqlplus` от Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_xplan.htm#ARPLS70125) предоставляет отличную возможность увидеть подробный план выполнения запроса в табличном виде (в виде текста):

```
set linesize 200 pages 3000
explain plan for <your SQL query>;
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);
```

Также можно посмотреть в бесплатном [Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html), нажав F10 или кнопку "Explain Plan"

Comment: Отличный ответ @iluxa1810 оставит наконец мышь в покое.

Comment: Справедливости ради, надо заметить, что бывают ситуации, когда explain показывает один план, а по факту выполнения используется другой

Comment: @0xdb, спасибо! :)

Comment: @Viktorov, в этом случае можно посмотреть план по `plan_hash_value`, воспользовавшись [DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_AWR(sql_id, plan_hash_value)](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_xplan.htm#ARPLS70134)

Answer (score 3):

В SQL*Plus есть еще один полезный режим работы, устанавливаемый с `SET AUTOTRACE`.
С этом режиме DML запрос будет выполнен, показан план его выполнения, и **дополнително** в созданой параллельно сессии будет собрана некоторая статистика выполнения запроса.

В [офф. док. гл. Tuning SQL*Plus](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/tuning-SQL-Plus.html#GUID-233D9103-017C-4832-B5E1-E38D32F9B00D) подробнее и с примерами.

Например, с параметром `TRACEONLY` будет полная трасировка, но без вывода в терминал результатов запроса:

```sql
SQL> set lines 999 autotrace traceonly

select *
from emp e join dept d on d.deptno = e.deptno;

14 rows selected.

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 844388907
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |         |    14 |   812 |     6  (17)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  MERGE JOIN                  |         |    14 |   812 |     6  (17)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| DEPT    |     4 |    80 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    INDEX FULL SCAN           | PK_DEPT |     4 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |   SORT JOIN                  |         |    14 |   532 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL         | EMP     |    14 |   532 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
   4 - access("D"."DEPTNO"="E"."DEPTNO")
       filter("D"."DEPTNO"="E"."DEPTNO")

Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          0  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
         10  consistent gets
          0  physical reads
          0  redo size
       1571  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        552  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          2  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          1  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
         14  rows processed
```

Answer (score 1):

В SQL Developer можно клавишей F10 визуализировать планы выполнения.
Есть возможность их экспорта как HTML. Этот инструмент безплатный.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]