# Как в IN вставить данные из подзапроса? - SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Возможно ли вставить в IN данные полученные из подзапроса?

Проблема заключается в следующем. Делаю селект со связкой из 3 таблиц и данные при этом не выгружаются, выгрузка виснет. Но если делать подзапрос для одной из таблицы с конкретным указанием поля сцепки то выгрузка происходит.

Пример выгрузки:

```
SELECT a.C1
      ,a.C2
      ,b.C1
      ,b.C2
      ,b.C3
      ,c.C1 
FROM table1 a LEFT JOIN table2 b ON a.ID=b.ID
              LEFT JOIN (SELECT * 
                         FROM table3 
                         WHERE ID IN ('123','123n',...) c ON c.ID=a.ID
WHERE a.C20 like 'Работает' AND a.C24 IS NULL
```

Как правильно составить SQL запрос?

Comment: Переместите подзапрос в CTE.

Comment: Думаю вам стоит вместо шаманства с переставлением частей запроса из одного места в другое посмотреть [план запроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/773497/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D1%81%D1%85%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-oracle/773594#773594) и уже от этого искать, как уйти от зависаний