# Как получить идентификатор запроса для плана его выполнения из таблицы с текущими сессиями?

Tags: sql, oracle, анализ-плана-запроса

Пытаюсь получить `id` последнего запроса вот так:

```
SELECT s.SQL_id, s.PREV_EXEC_START, s.OSUSER, s.* 
FROM v$session s 
WHERE lower(s.osuser) LIKE '%my_user%';
```

Но Оракл выводит в таблицу всего одну запись, которая и является выполнением запроса указанного выше.

Я пытаюсь получить детальный план запроса как описано тут:
 [Визуализатор схем-выполненя запросов в Oracle](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/773497/%d0%92%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d1%81%d1%85%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-oracle)

Comment: Так и с чем у вас трудности? Полученый `sql_id` вставляете как параметр и получаете план выполнения запроса.

Comment: @0xdb  у меня получается, что в этой таблице v$session id селекта, это id этого селекта SELECT s.SQL_id, s.PREV_EXEC_START, s.OSUSER, s.* FROM v$session s WHERE lower(s.osuser) LIKE '%my_user%';
и больше нет записей

Comment: Всё правильно, это и есть ваш текущий запрос. А сколько у вас сессий? Если одна, то и будет одна запись.

Comment: Если ответ не помог с решением, то добавте пожалуйста в вопрос больше деталей. Может я не совсем понял вашу задачу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В представлении `v$session` столбец `sql_id` указывает на находящийся на выполнении запрос. То есть, ограничив запрос условием, с которым в результате будет только текущая сессия, то и будет найден текущий запрос.

Попробуйте, как указано в [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_XPLAN.html#GUID-0EE333AF-E9AC-40A4-87D5-F6CF59D6C47B):

> `sql_id` - [...] This parameter defaults to NULL in which case the plan of the last cursor executed by the session is displayed.

опустить параметр `sql_id`, чтобы посмотерть план последнего выполненого запроса:

```
select count (job_id)
from hr.employees where job_id = 'IT_PROG';

select * from table (dbms_xplan.display_cursor ());
```

Или можно узнать предпоследний запрос в столбце `prev_sql_id`:

```
col prev_sql_id new_value prevSqlId noprint 
select prev_sql_id, s.* 
from v$session s 
where username = user;

select * from table (dbms_xplan.display_cursor (sql_id=>'&prevSqlId'));
```

И наконец, наиболее гибкий способ (измените условие в `where` на желаемое):

```
select sql_id, substr (sql_text,1,200) text 
from  v$sql
where parsing_schema_name = user and sql_text like '%count%emp%';
```